# how to remove number of badge one by one while scrolling

Tags: iphone, ipad, icarousel

I want to remove the badge number from my iPhone application icon when a user scrolls. I'm using iCarousel class' `carouselDidScroll` method. Unfortunately, the code I'm using (below) doesn't work, and the badge number remains visible. Any ideas?

```
- (void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    int badge=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badge--];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the postfix decrement operator decrements its operand, but it yields its previous (not yet decremented) value. Why not use `badge - 1` or `--badge` instead?

Comment: okie..this is fine..but if there are 3 badge number on app icon..and while open the app,all 3 badge is disappear..what i want,while i scroll this badge number will disappear one by one.

Comment: @Sweeta Well, that's a different question.